# How to set my button width to "wrap_content" inside the GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

My buttons are being overflow inside the gridlayout because their length are being long from the start unnecessarily. I just want to set them `wrap_content` to all of them. I was doing [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677) tutorial. Here's my code.

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/characterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/keyOptionLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvLotteryNumber"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="a" />

    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="b" />

    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="c" />

    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="d" />

    <Button
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="e" />

</GridLayout>
```

Removing `android_layout_row="0"` lines doesn't change anything. 
Here's how they displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp'
```

to your buttons and add

```
grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

to your buttons.
Don't forget to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
 namepsace to your `GridLayout`

Comment: It doesn't work. And all buttons are gone. I don't think I need xmls:android since my GridLayout is not the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Using `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` solved the issue.

1. In Gradle, `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'`
2. I changed my code as the correct answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606789/gridlayout-going-out-of-bounds/34608892#34608892) question.

**Result:**

[image]